# Schedule many Push Notifications in React Naitve

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an app where I'm using push notifications with help of Firebase Cloud Messaging and 'react-native-notifications' library. I managed to schedule a push notification in background.
Now I wonder, how can I schedule many push notifications (in background). Let's say, I have an array of strings and I want to make a push notification with a different string every day.
I know how I can make it with local notification but it means that the notification will not appear if the app is closed. Do you have an idea how it can be solved?

Comment: If you managed to schedule one push notification, can't you perform that same process multiple times to schedule many push notifications?

Comment: And if i need to create hundres of notifications (with different notification text)? I prefer not to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you managed to "show" a push notification when you are focused in the app.

If you want to send push notifications while your app is in the background you would need to use [Firebase FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Also if you need to send them in specific intervals I would recommend to use the [Firebase callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to do so.

Comment: Thank you! I'm already using FCM. I wonder, if it's possible to use an array of strings when I create a notification in Cloud Messaging, instead of making hundreds of notifications manually.

Comment: You can send a single message (same content) to topics and multiple tokens but you can't send different messages (different content) with a single request/command. As Puff mentioned in the command you would need to make multiple calls. If you have an array of string I would loop over it to send the messages.

Comment: I should use Firebase callable functions to loop over my array, right?

Comment: Yes. Either save tha array to one of the databases or send it directly to your callable function.